# any idea why sinon is not producing an xml response object?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, xmlhttprequest, sinon, sinon-chai

that I use mocha+sinonjs for unit testing. So far it worked well, but now I try to run a unit test which should produce an xml response on an ajax request. This works up until the point where I want to query the request.responseXML object, which is always null, despite having passed all needed parameters for Sinon to parse the xml. I have added a small typescript based unit test to show the problem.

```js
describe('Sinon XML Problem', function () {
    it("must work with xml", function () {
        let FakeXMLHTTPequest = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();

        var requests = this.requests = [];
        FakeXMLHTTPequest.onCreate = function (xhr) {
            requests.push(xhr);
        };
        let xhr: any = new FakeXMLHTTPequest();
        requests[0].responseType = 'document';
        requests[0].open('GET', '/xmlhttprequest/xml', false);

        requests[0].onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (requests[0].readyState == 4) {
                expect(requests[0].responseXML != null).to.be.true;
            }
        };

        requests[0].send();

        requests[0].respond(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}, `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <partial-response>
        <changes>
            <update id="value_1"><![CDATA[<span id="out1">2</span>]]></update>
            <update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[j_id1:j_id3]]></update>
        </changes>
    </partial-response>
    `);

    })
});
```

the result from requests[0].responseXML should be anything but null, but the test fails with a null on the responseXML. Does anyone know why?